# Twisted spin cobordism v.s. KO theory in low dimensions

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, spectral-sequences, cobordism

Based on the [background info](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312050/27004) and this [this webpage](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Spin_bordism#Classification), here is a more advanced problem:

**Question**: If we consider a different more subtle twisted structure, like
$${\Omega_d^{(\mathrm{spin} \times G)/N}},$$ 
where $N$ is a normal subgroup shared by the $\operatorname{spin}$ and $G$ (e.g. $N=\mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $N \subset \operatorname{spin}(d)$ and $N \subset G$.)
What is the difference/comparison/discrepency between Spin cobordism v.s. KO theory, do we have 
$$\Omega_d^{(\mathrm{spin} \times G)/N} = \text{certain } ko  \text{ theory?}$$ 
or generally
$$\Omega_d^{(\mathrm{spin} \times G)/N} \neq \text{certain } ko  \text{ theory},$$
what are the differences in low dimensions (say $d \leq 7$?) or maybe other dimensions?